# Open PDF in Android without it Automatically Being Downloaded To Device

Tags: android, pdf, mobile, download, mobile-website

I have a mobile responsive website where users enter login credentials to gain access to view
pdf files inside my portal.

When viewing the website on my android phone, if a pdf is opened from inside the portal, my android phone automatically downloads a copy of the pdf on the android phone and then opens it.

This same process on a laptop or desktop simply opens the pdf in the default browser.  There is a download button, but it is not automatically downloaded on the device.

From a programming standpoint, is there a way a programmer could prevent the PDF document from being automatically downloaded on the android phone and just have the document viewable in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by downloaded.  Whenever you view ANYTHING on the web, you have to download it.  Downloading is the process of receiving data from a remote source.  You have to download any webpage or url to view it.

It seems what you're asking is "Does it have to be saved to a file in the Downloads folder".  In which case no, it doesn't.  You could download it and keep it in RAM.